# Clone rep:policy on AEM

Tags: aem, jcr

I am currently working on with a solution that would be able to clone/copy/backup my existing rep:policy. 'Cause when we do some jobs it accidentally removed. I am trying to apply this kind of fix, but am failing to. It says it is an invalid path.

> javax.jcr.security.AccessControlException: OakAccessControl0006: Isolated policy node. Parent is not of type [rep:AccessControllable]

```
        final Workspace ws = session.getWorkspace();
           ws.copy("/etc/commerce/products/abccompany/TvPackChannelMap/rep:policy","/tmp/nxt/TvPackChannelMap/rep:policy");
```

Are there other ways that I can be able to take the rep:policy thru code?

Answer (score 0):

> You need to make sure that your job does not touch the permissions or the rep:policy, this is the best way forward for you.

The exception could be because of `/etc/commerce/products/abccompany/TvPackChannelMap/rep:policy` does not exist or the user whose `session` you are using does not have read access to the node.

Make sure the path is correct, copy paste it to your CRX/DE to make sure it exists.

I have tried to use your code to copy a `rep:policy` from one node to another, works fine. But I would **not*** recommend copying permissions that way. The best practice is to use the [Access Control Management API](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/security/accesscontrol/editing.html) for all things permissions.

Comment: The path exists and I'm using an admin account.

Answer (score 0):

You can check, install and use the [access control tool](https://github.com/Netcentric/accesscontroltool/blob/develop/docs/Migration.md) from netcentric. It offers a jmx interface for exporting AC entries and maybe also some APIs you could use to implement your custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Other approach is to retrieve the ACL permissions through the query language. 
For example, SELECT * FROM [rep:ACL]  or SELECT * FROM [rep:ACE] where [rep:principalName] is not null should give you the results.

For more information, I would recommend you to check the ACS commons ACL Packager Implementation which is available on GitHub.
Reference Link - https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/commons/packaging/impl/ACLPackagerServletImpl.java